# How to calcuate $(a+bi)^n$ without using the De Moivre's formula?

Tags: complex-numbers

Sometimes, I need to calculate the value of $(a+bi)^n$ but without using  De Moivre's formula. Is there a method to do that and what is its name?? thanks

Comment: Like binomial expansion ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner is suggesting that you just use the binomial expansion. There's nothing else "like it" for this job.

Comment: @Mustafa What exactly do you want to use then?

Comment: How can you *need* to calculate without DeMoivre?  Well, you can always do $\sum_{k=0;k\equiv 0\pmod 4}^nb^{k}a^{n-k}{n\choose k} - \sum_{k=2;k\equiv 2\pmod4}^n b^{k}a^{n-k}{n\choose k} + i(\sum_{k=1;k\equiv 1\pmod 4}^nb^{k}a^{n-k}{n\choose k}-\sum_{k=3;k\equiv 0\pmod 4}^nb^{k}a^{n-k}{n\choose k})$.

Comment: "I want to do something that it's known how to do but I don't want to use any of those ways of doing".

Comment: @Azif00 sorry but I remember there is another way

Comment: Well, if you remember another way then it's up to you to teach *us* how to do it.

Comment: @fleablood I don't remember the details

Answer (score 1):

You can use the binomial theorem,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k} a^k (ib)^{n-k} = (a+ib)^n$$